# What security risks are presented when using Flex

Tags: apache-flex, security

I've been presented with completing a new project and was considering Flex for the UI component. I was wondering what security risks are present when using Flex.

Answer (score 3):

The same security risks you would have with an Ajax UI. You are still making remote requests from the browser to the server. They will either be normal HTTP requests or AMF, but either way, if they don't go over SSL/TLS they can be sniffed and intercepted.

Some might argue that Flash is "full of vulnerabilities (just like browsers and any desktop software that connects to remote systems can have), those vulnerabilities are usually related to the player being exploited by malicious content, not a legit Flash/Flex application being vulnerable to attack. Though that is possible (just like it is with an HTML/JS application) if you code your application intelligently, and are careful with user input you can mitigate those threats.

I hope this adequately answers your question.